# Can't see why I'm getting undefined method form_for

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord, controller

I don't get why I'm getting this error

```
undefined method `sector_id' for #<Portfolio:0x007fe17c2e3848>
```

I have a Portfolio Model and a Sector model, they look like so

```
class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sector
  attr_accessible :overview, :title, :sector_id
end



class Sector < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :portfolios
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

My routes

```
resources :portfolios do
  resources :sectors
end
```

So within my form to create a new portfolio I have this collection_select

```
<%= f.label :sector_id, "Choose Sector", :class => 'title_label' %><br>
<%= f.collection_select(:sector_id, Sector.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Please Select a Sector") %>
```

This is something I've done many times before and it has worked, can anyone see why I would be getting this error?

The only thing I can think of is that I have called my controller for portfolio as Portfolios, I always get mixed up with plural and singular controller names, would this make a difference in my case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you have not run the migration yet that adds the column "sector_id" in your table "portfolios". If you are using MySQL connect to your database and check the table (`show create table portfolios;`). Use appropriate method to get this info from your database server if you are using other rdbms. Alternatively, in your rails console (`rails c`) type in `Portofolio` and see what attributes it prints out. Does it include `sector_id`?